# Find the angle between two points

Tags: code-golf, math, trigonometry

Given two points `A` and `B`, find the angle from line `AO` to line `BO` about point `O` where `O` is the origin (`(0,0)`). Additionally, the angle may be positive or negative depending on the positions of the points (see examples). Input will be points `A` and `B`, and may be given in any convenient form. Output will be the angle in degrees (but it is positive if `AO` is rotated counter-clockwise about the origin to get `BO` and negative if it is rotated clockwise). If the angle is 180 degrees you may return a negative or positive output. Similarly, the angle can be the positive or negative version of the same angle (`90 deg` is equal to `-270 deg`). Examples:

- Input: `A(5,5) B(5,-5)` Output: `-90` (`AO` is rotated `-90` degrees to get `BO`).
- Input: `A(5,-5) B(5,5)` Output: `90` (`AO` is rotated `90` degrees to get `BO`).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Your examples only have multiples of 90 degs in them. Is this true for our programs as well, or do they have to deal with arbitrary angles?

Comment: Arbitrary angles as well.

Comment: How much precision is required?

Comment: Can we take input as two complex numbers?

Comment: Can we output as a one-element list containing the angle?

Comment: What should the output be if one point is `(0,0)`?

Comment: @ThomasKwa I don't know about the OP, but I treated it as only integer/decimal number input, and the input would never have a (0,0) point.

Comment: Hint: The angle between `AO` and `BO` would usually be called angle `AOB`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
.t-FPM.jMQ6
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.t-FPM.jMQ6&input=%5B%5B1%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+0%5D%5D&debug=0)

Input is given in the format:

```
[[Bx, By], [Ax, Ay]]
```

If it is desired that A comes first, this can be changed for 1 byte.

Explanation:

```
.t-FPM.jMQ6
               Implicit: Q = eval(input())
      .jMQ     Convert input pairs to complex numbers.
    PM         Take their phases (angles in the complex plane).
  -F           Take the difference.
.t        6    Convert to degrees
```

Answer (score 21):

## TI-BASIC, 13 bytes

For TI-83+/84+ series calculators.

```
Degree
Input Y
min(ΔList(R►Pθ(Ans,∟Y
```

To use this program, enter the list `{x1,x2}` through the Ans variable, and `{y1,y2}` at the prompt.

Comment: Is a TI-BASIC command a single byte?

Comment: All commands here, except `ΔList(`, are [one byte](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens) each. This includes `R►Pθ(`.

Comment: +1 just for using calculator programming. Takes me back to Trig and Calculus in my high school days.

Comment: Nice reference! Super cool.

Answer (score 10):

## CJam, 14 bytes

```
q~::ma:-P/180*
```

This is a full program that reads the input as `[[Ax Ay] [Bx By]]` from STDIN.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3A%3Ama%3A-P%2F180*&input=%5B%5B5%205%5D%20%5B5%20-5%5D%5D).

#### How it works

```
q~             e# Read and evaluate all input.
  ::ma         e# Replace each point (x, y) with atan2(x, y).
               e# This returns its angle with the positive y axis, measured clockwise.
      :-       e# Compute the difference of the two resulting angles.
               e# This returns the angle between the points, measured counter-clockwise.
        P/180* e# Divide by Pi and multiply by 180 to convert to degrees.
```

Comment: Amusing that almost half of this program is just converting radians to degrees...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I find it even more amusing that in Pyth the conversion is 3 bytes instead of 6, so if the challenge allowed for reporting in radians the languages would be tied

Answer (score 4):

### [Minkolang 0.9](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 112 bytes

I *really* want to implement trig functions as built-ins now...but this was fun! (Caveat: this outputs the positive angle difference, not the signed angle difference. Given my limitations, I think that's justified.)

```
4[n]0c2c*1c3c*+r4[2;1R]r+1R+0g*12$:;$:8[0ci2*3+d1R;0g$:1i1+[i2*1+d1+$:*]*]$+'3.141592654'25*9;$:$:12$:r-66*5**N.
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=4%5Bn%5D0c2c*1c3c*%2Br4%5B2%3B1R%5Dr%2B1R%2B0g*12%24%3A%3B%24%3A8%5B0ci2*3%2Bd1R%3B0g%24%3A1i1%2B%5Bi2*1%2Bd1%2B%24%3A*%5D*%5D%24%2B%273%2E141592654%2725*9%3B%24%3A%24%3A12%24%3Ar-66*5**N.&input=1%202%201%20-2)

#### Explanation

I'll post a fuller explanation if anyone wants it, but the gist of it is:

```
4[n]                                    Take in 4 integers from input
0c2c*1c3c*+                             dot product
r4[2;1R]r+1R+0g*12$:;                   magnitudes of vectors
$:                                      dot product divided by magnitudes (z)
8[0ci2*3+d1R;0g$:1i1+             *]    Taylor series for arccos
                     [i2*1+d1+$:*]      In particular, the coefficient (1/2 * 3/4 * ...)
$+                                      Add them all up!
'3.141592654'25*9;$:$:                  Divide by pi for converting to degrees
12$:r-                                  Subtract from 1/2 - I now have arccos(z)
66*5**                                  Convert to degrees
N.                                      Output as number and stop.
```

Comment: Does minkolang support comments? I couldn't find it on the readme.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: It's just like other 2D languages - comments are whatever isn't reached by the program counter.

Comment: Oh, okay, then. That makes sense, dunno what I was thinking.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: Your explicit use of comments in one of your answers makes me consider implementing similar functionality though. It's a neat idea and wouldn't be terribly hard for me to implement.

Comment: Thanks! `:D` Was it the Hello World challenge that you noticed the comments in (FYI the interpreter I have made for Simplex runs in different "modes": string mode and comment mode. It makes it really easy to parse and allows you to ignore signal characters of one mode whilst in the other.)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: Yep. My interpreter does the same for string mode and number mode. It would not be hard to add comment mode.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 22 bytes

```
{-1,1.}.ArcTan@@@#/°&
```

**Example:**

```
In[1]:= {-1,1.}.ArcTan@@@#/°&[{{5,5},{5,-5}}]

Out[1]= -90.

In[2]:= {-1,1.}.ArcTan@@@#/°&[{{5,-5},{5,5}}]

Out[2]= 90.
```

Comment: Will this work for inputs like `{{0,1},{1,0}}`

Comment: @ThomasKwa Of course it will.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>18</s> 25 bytes

```
f(A,B)=angle(B/A)/pi*180
```

This assumes that "any convenient form" already allows for `A` and `B` to be given as complex numbers. Then, the [complex number arithmetic](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/complex-and-rational-numbers/) does all the heavy lifting.

*Edit: converted snippet to function. 18 byte version only works in the Julia REPL.*

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.7, 73 Bytes

```python
from math import*
f=lambda A,B:degrees(atan2(B[1],B[0])-atan2(A[1],A[0]))
```

**Test:**

```
f((5,5),(5,-5)) #-90.0
f((5,-5),(5,5)) #90.0
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is code-golf, so you should try to remove as many spaces as you can and shorten your code.

Comment: You can make your code shorter by recklessly adding some `*`s [all over the place](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#from%20math%20import%2a%0Alambda%20A%2CB%3Adegrees%28atan2%28%2aB%5B%3A%3A-1%5D%29-atan2%28%2aA%5B%3A%3A-1%5D%29%29)

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 43 bytes

```
f=@(a,b)(cart2pol(b)-cart2pol(a))(1)*180/pi
```

Input/Output:

```
octave:40> f([5,5],[5,-5])
ans = -90

octave:41> f([1,0],[0,1])
ans = 90
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, 66 bytes

```
let f=(a,b)=>(Math.atan2(b.y,b.x)-Math.atan2(a.y,a.x))*180/Math.PI;
```

[demo](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ig8epjjd/)

Comment: 23 seconds before me =P Nice golf though! Btw, you can omit the `let f=`, and it's still considered valid as an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
l~ma@@ma-P/180*
```

Thought I'll get in the CJam game as well. [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%7Ema%40%40ma-P%2F180*&input=5%20-5%205%205).
Input is in form of `bx by ax ay`. Unfortunately, this is the shortest method of doing this challenge without copying Dennis' answer.

Answer (score 2):

## TeaScript, 28 bytes

I really should of implemented trig functions...

```
$.atan2(_[3]-y,z-x)*180/$.PI
```

[Try it online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/?code=%24.atan2(_%5B3%5D-y%2Cz-x)*180%2F%24.PI&input=5) input is `a.x a.y b.x b.y`

#### Explanation

```
$.atan2(       // Arc Tangent of...
    _[3] - y,  // 4th input - 2nd input
       z - x,  // 3rd input - 1st input
) * 180 / $.PI // Converts rad -> deg
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <strike>64</strike>, 58 bytes

```
a=->(b){b.map{|c|Math.atan2(*c)}.reduce(:-)*180/Math::PI}
```

Usage

```
a.call [[5, 5], [5, -5]] # => -90.0
a.call [[5, -5], [5, 5]] # => 90.0
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 49 bytes

```
(a,b)=>((c=Math.atan2)(...b)-c(...a))/Math.PI*180
```

Input is taken in form: `[aY, aX], [bY, bX]` (notice the reversed x/y)

Answer (score 1):

## [Simplex v.0.7](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Simplex/), 13 bytes

I'm glad I added `mathrelations` :D Unfortunately, I cannot take pointwise input. So, I input each point as a separate number (Ax, Ay, Bx, By). (I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26076956/4119004) as a resource.)

```
(iRi~^fR)2LSo
(       )2    ~~ repeat inner twice
 iRi          ~~ take two chars of input (x,y)
    ~         ~~ switch top 2 on stack
     ^f       ~~ apply atan2 on (y,x)
       R      ~~ go right
          L   ~~ go left
           S  ~~ subtract result
            o ~~ output as number
```

I can save a char if I can take input as (Ay, Ax, By, Bx):

```
(iRi^fR)2LSo
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 88 bytes

```c
#include<math.h>
typedef double d;d g(d x,d y,d a,d b){return atan2(b-y,a-x)*180/M_PI;}
```

Requires compiling with GCC to take advantage of `M_PI` being defined in `math.h` as a part of [GCC's built-in math constants](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mathematical-Constants.html).
[Try it online](http://ideone.com/OunR8Y) - since ideone doesn't use GCC (apparently), an additional few bytes are needed for enough digits of π to be accurate.

Comment: Or `45/atan(1)` instead of `180/3.14159....` (in the online demo).

Comment: @CompuChip I wasn't trying to make the online demo maximally golfed

Comment: You can remove the brackets round atan2(b-y,a-x), although you then need a space after return so it only saves 1 byte.  If you can use K&R style functions then double g(x,y,a,b)double x,y,a,b; also saves six bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 33 bytes

```
f=\(a,b,c,d)atan2(d-b,c-a)/pi*180
```

result:

```
> f(5,5,5,-5)
[1] -90
> f(5,-5,5,5)
[1] 90
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 68 Bytes

Pascal according to ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” includes complex numbers as a built‑in data type.

```pascal
function f(A,B:complex):real;begin f:=arg(B/A)*90/arg(cmplx(0,1))end
```

### FreePascal, 71 Bytes

As of version 3.2.0 the [FreePascal Compiler](https://www.FreePascal.org/) (FPC) does not (yet) support (all) Extended Pascal features, but the standard RTL (run‑time library) includes a custom `ucomplex` UCSD Pascal `unit` providing a `record`‑based complex number implementation.

```pascal
uses uComplex;function f(A,B:complex):real;begin f:=180/pi*carg(B/A)end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 62 bytes

```swift
import Foundation
let f={(atan2($3,$2)-atan2($1,$0))*180/M_PI}
```

If you're on a Mac, you should be able to replace `import Foundation` with `import Darwin` to save 4 bytes.